# How to group by and filter within the groups pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am looking to add an aggregate column to a DataFrame that looks something like this:

`pd.DataFrame({"col1" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "col2" : ["b", "b", "b", "a", "b"], "col3": [6, 2, 11, 1, 3]})`

When I aggregate I want to filter on a column value. So for the example DataFrame above for each row I would want to find the mean of the values of "col1" which have the same value for "col2" and a lower value than it's "col3" value.

So for row 0 want the value of the mean of (2, 5) = 3.5

My intended result would look like this :

`pd.DataFrame({"col1" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "col2" : ["b", "b", "b", "a", "b"], "col3": [6, 2, 11, 1, 3], "mean_col" : [3.5, None, 2.666, None, 2.0]})`

I could do something like this but I would rather not iterate through the df:

```
mean_vals = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # ensure same group
    grouped_df = df[df.col2 == row["col2"]]
    
    # apply condition
    grouped_and_filtered_df = grouped_df[grouped_df.col3 < row["col3"]]
    
    # aggregation
    row_mean = grouped_and_filtered_df.col1.mean()
    
    mean_vals.append(row_mean)
```

Comment: For row 0, I'd expect `mean([2, 5])` -> `3.5`. Can you clarify and fix the expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) your data, aggregating as `sum` and `count`, [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `col3`, then [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get the sum and count of all values of lower "col3". Now you will be able to compute the mean by dividing `sum` by `count` and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)ed output to the original data:

```
tmp = (df.pivot_table(index='col3', columns='col2',
                      values='col1', aggfunc=['sum', 'count'])
         .sort_index().cumsum().shift()
      )

out = df.merge(tmp['sum'].div(tmp['count']).stack()
                         .reset_index(name='mean_col'),
               how='left')
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2  col3  mean_col
0     1    b     6  3.500000
1     2    b     2       NaN
2     3    b    11  2.666667
3     4    a     1       NaN
4     5    b     3  2.000000
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
      sum      count     
col2    a    b     a    b
col3                     
1     NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
2     4.0  NaN   1.0  NaN
3     NaN  2.0   NaN  1.0
6     NaN  7.0   NaN  2.0
11    NaN  8.0   NaN  3.0
```

---

If you have a lot a groups with very different values in col3, you can also apply the same logic per group to avoid building a large intermediate.

```
def mean_lower(g):
    tmp = (g.groupby('col3')['col1']
            .agg(['sum', 'count'])
            .sort_index().cumsum().shift()
          )
    return g.merge(tmp['sum'].div(tmp['count'])
                             .reset_index(name='mean_col'),
                   how='left').set_axis(g.index)

out = df.groupby('col2', group_keys=False).apply(mean_lower)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2  col3  mean_col
0     1    b     6  3.500000
1     2    b     2       NaN
2     3    b    11  2.666667
3     4    a     1       NaN
4     5    b     3  2.000000
```

Intermediates:

```
# group "a"
      sum  count
col3            
1     NaN    NaN

# group "b"
      sum  count
col3            
2     NaN    NaN
3     2.0    1.0
6     7.0    2.0
11    8.0    3.0
```